# How can I update libavcodec to 57?

Tags: 14.04, apt, compiling, vlc

I am trying to build VLC player on Ubuntu 14.04.

It's been a tough road but I am learning along the way. However I am really stuck with this lib `libavcodec` that is required as prompted by this message.

```
configure: error: Requested 'libavcodec >= 57.16.0' but version of libavcodec is 54.35.0. Pass --disable-avcodec to ignore this error.
```

What I don't understand is why `apt` does not have `libavcodec` above 54. Is this a common issue where libs are updated, but not on `apt`? If so how do I got about getting the version I need?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for 14.04, only `libavcodec54` is available. You can choose to ignore the error by following the suggested route, i.e `Pass --disable-avcodec to ignore this error`. You can also try installing `libavcodec-dev` and see if it is working.

Comment: Oh, I understand. It seems crazy to pass this disable parameter, as I think most of VLC won't work without it. How can I figure out what version of Ubuntu would work with libavcodec 57?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works for 14.04 too, but for 16.10: you have to add an additional repository `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main universe` to get this newer version. You will find details instructions here: https://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/yakkety/universe/l/libavcodec-extra57/install/index.html